# Write generic function to open modal

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazored

have the following situation. In my razor page I have 40 buttons, each one opens one of 40 Blazored-modals:

```
<div class="row">
    ...
    <button type="button" @onclick="@(() => ShowComBoxModal())">
      ComBox Parameters
    </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  ...
    <button type="button" @onclick="@(() => ShowGTLSModal())">
        GTLS Parameters
    </button>
</div>
```

For each of the 40 modals I wrote a routine to open the modal, e.g.:

```
void ShowComBoxModal()
    {
        var parameters = new ModalParameters();
        parameters.Add("PkId", CurrentD5User.PkId);
        parameters.Add("SystemID", 7);
        parameters.Add("cfg", cfgComBox);

        ModalService.Show<ModalComBox>("ComBox", parameters);    
    }

void ShowGTLSModal()
    {
        var parameters = new ModalParameters();
        parameters.Add("PkId", CurrentD5User.PkId);
        parameters.Add("SystemID", 8);
        parameters.Add("cfg", cfgGtls);

        ModalService.Show<ModalGTLS>("GTLS", parameters);    
    }
```

I would like to eliminate the redundancy of having almost the same code 40 times by writing one generic method. Problem is, I can pass the PkId and the SystemID to that method because they are strings, but I'm really having trouble to a) have the modal object to call in the <> part of the .Show method and b) hand over the because every cfgObject is of one of 40 different types and I would have to cast it back to its original type. I would like to have something like that:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="@(() => ShowGTLSModal<ModalGTLS>(@CurrentD5User.PkId, 8, "cfgGtls"))">
            GTLS Parameters
        </button>

void ShowModal<T>(string PkId, string SystemID, object cfgObject) 
{
var parameters = new ModalParameters();
parameters.Add("PkId", PkId);
parameters.Add("SystemID", SystemID);
parameters.Add("cfg", cfgObject);

ModalService.Show<T>("GTLS", parameters);    
}
```

My cfgObjects are of different types:

```
GoodwillPkw cfgGodwill = new GoodwillPkw();
ComBox cfgComBox = new ComBox();
Gtls cfgGtls = new Gtls();
ConnectMe cfgConnectMe = new ConnectMe();
...
```

So I would have to cast that object back to its original type AND have the Show-method use the type  that I receive in that method. The latter I would be able to achieve in each of the 40 Modal component classes. But I am having trouble to add the modal component class in the <> element.

Is that possibly somehow?